# Calculation of the string as expression in C++

Tags: c++

In my project i need to take an expression input from user as string and then show the result of the expression. I am taking the input as follows

```
char address[100] = {NULL};
fgets(address, 100, stdin); //take the expression as input here
```

say user wrote the expression as

```
address = " 1+5+9" .
```

What i need to do is to show the result of the expression. I can do this by separating each number and then doing the calculation. But i just wanted to know is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Look up postfix expression evaluation and usage of stack

Comment: You can start by using `std::cin` or `std::getline`, as well as  `std::string`.

Comment: Nope, this is the best way to do it. In fact, to evaluate complex mathematical expressions like `(3+2) * (1 - (3 * 2 + 1) / 4 + 1 ^ 5)` you need to implement a recursive descent parser using something like YACC or Bison. **PS:** This is hard to do.

Comment: Stroustrup devotes an entire chapter to this problem in "The C++ programming language".

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps, I like that chapter.  I learned a lot from it.

Comment: @Hans, the best way to evaluate complex mathematical expressions is still stack and usage of Reverse Polish Notation. RDP is way to complex for such simple evaluation. **PS**: your example does not qualify as "complex mathematical expression".

Comment: @Griwes `3 * 2 + 1` is hard to parse because of order of operations, as is `/ 4 + 1 ^ 5`. RPN is nice but unless if you are forcing your users to write in RPN then you are going to have to write a parser that takes standard math expressions and turn it into RPN.

Comment: @Hans, it's not hard to parse expressions with operators with different priorities not being separated by brackets. It's really simple algorithm, which is, I think, described on one of wikipedia pages (I'm 100% sure it's on Polish version of RPN article, not sure whether or where on English version).

Comment: Thanks guys for helping. Now understand there is no simple way except parsing. Though i am new but i will give it a try.

Comment: @Hans You don't need Yacc or Bison---they're probably overkill for something this simple.  And they don't generate recursive descent parsers---I would use a (hand written) recursive descent parser here.  They're extremely simple to write.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use `NULL` to initialize an array of `char`.
`NULL` is traditionally used for pointers, not `char`, and a
good compiler will generate a warning if you use it in a non-pointer
context.  (Of course, you should be using `std::string` anyway.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's sounds like you're looking for a C++ equivalent to something like `eval` in JavaScript.  Unfortunately, C++ doesn't have one.  Parsing the expression by hand is the best you can do.

If you have access to [The C++ Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201889544) book, chapter 6 covers how one would write a simple calculator program, solving the same problem you have.

Comment: Thanks guys for helping. Now understand there is no simple way except parsing. Though i am new but i will give it a try.

Comment: Being new to programming is a great reason to try writing a parser by hand, even if C++ had an automated way to do it.  You'll learn a lot from it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches for doing this, one of the most popular ways, and in my personal oppinion most elegant ways, is to use a recursive descent parser. There are lots of useful guides to doing this on the web. A simple google search led me to:

- [Creating a Recursive-Descent Parser](http://knuth.luther.edu/~leekent/tutorials/ll1.html)
- [Recursive Descent Parsing](http://www.cs.engr.uky.edu/~lewis/essays/compilers/rec-des.html)
- [Recursive Descent Parser in C++](http://dmitrybrant.com/2003/08/18/recursive-descent-parser-in-c)
- [Parsing Expressions by Recursive Descent (contains some useful pseudo code)](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/Misc/exp_parsing.htm)

Also these Stack Overflow posts:

- [Recursive descent parser questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436819/recursive-descent-parser-questions)
- [Recursive Descent Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767965/recursive-descent-parser)

The problem with simply seperating the numbers and then doing the calculation is the problems that occur when you allow multiplication and generally needs to consider the order of operators.